# Trouble Using Buildozer on Debian 12 for Android Development - Seeking Assistance

Tags: python-3.x, buildozer, android-developer-api, libffi, debian-bookworm

I used to use Buildozer on Ubuntu 20.04 without any issues for Android app development using Kivy. However, since switching to Debian 12, I've encountered difficulties getting Buildozer to run reliably.

I'd like to know if anyone has managed to get Buildozer working on Debian 12 and, if so, what steps were taken to achieve this. My previous attempts haven't been successful, and I'm seeking advice or solutions to continue developing my Android applications from my Debian system.

I'm open to any suggestions, configuration changes, or specific Debian 12 procedures that might make Buildozer functional.

Any help or shared experiences would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've been encountering issues while trying to utilize Python-for-Android on Debian 12 for Android app development. Initially, I encountered an AttributeError, which I managed to resolve by following this link https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/2745 .

However, I'm now facing an ImportError related to libffi.so.7 while running the build process:
`from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array ImportError: libffi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` 
I attempted to create a symbolic link from libffi.so.8 to libffi.so.7 using sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7, but I'm now encountering this error:
`from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7: version` LIBFFI_BASE_7.0' not found (required by /home/fab/PycharmProject_CasseBriques/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/_ctypes.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
`
I'm uncertain if this issue is common or if there are workarounds or alternative approaches used by others who have successfully run Buildozer on Debian 12.

I'd greatly appreciate any insights, experiences, or guidance from the community. If anyone has overcome similar challenges or found a different way to make Buildozer work smoothly on Debian 12, I'd love to hear about it.

Thank you for your help and suggestions in advance!

Edit: Temporarily, I'm using an Ubuntu 22.04 vm to compile with Buildozer, but this solution doesn't work for me. So if you've managed to get Buildozer working with Debian12, please let me know.